# Modal only works for the first post

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am creating a edit post button in which the user clicks the button and a modal with the form pops up to edit the form. For some reason, only the button on the first post will work and open the modal. Not sure what i'm doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.The post form in the modal is for testing.

home.php:

```
@if($posts)
                @foreach($posts as $post)
            <div class="card" style="margin-top: 20px">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div>{{$post->user->name}}</div>
                    <div id="post-date">{{$post->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</div>
                </div>


                <div class="card-body">
                    <div>{{$post->body}}</div>
                    @if(!empty($post->photo_id ))
                        <img class="post-image"src="/images/{{ $post->photo->file }}" alt="">
                    @else
                        <img class="post-image" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="">
                    @endif



                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div>
                            <button class="btn-primary btn-sm" id="edit-post-btn">Edit Post</button>

                            <!-- The Modal -->
                            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ route('makePost')  }}">
                                        @csrf

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="body" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Body') }}</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="body" type="text" class="form-control" name="body" value="{{ old('body') }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <label for="photo" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Photo') }}</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <input id="photo" type="file" class="form-control" name="photo_id" value="{{ old('photo') }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                                    {{ __('Submit Post') }}
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                </div>
            </div>
                @endforeach
                @endif
```

JS file:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("edit-post-btn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target === modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: Your repeating ids.  Id's are expected to be unique.  `getElementById` is only going to find one single element by the id.  Which is why it is `getElement` and not `getElements`.  Use a class instead.

Comment: Agree...your ID (identifier) muss be unique, as it identiefies the object. Btw.: Please format your code propperly, it makes reading really hard...

Comment: Changed my id's to classes and changed getElementById to getElementsByClassName. Now nothing works. the modal won't pop up on any post when clicked